# 508 Accessibility: English Siri misreads certain roman numerals

Tags: ios, siri, accessibility, voiceover

For any multiple of 5 and its preceding value, Siri reads the value as a literal character rather than a number. For instance, the numbers `4, 5, 9, 10` are read as the characters `I-V, V, I-X, X` rather their numeric equivalent. I assume this is the case for all Siri languages, but I'm only concerned with English.

UPDATE: I'm not sure how I can clarify my request. Siri speaks *certain* roman numerals (not all) as characters meaning that it doesn't recognize them as numerals, but text. Why the inconsistency? It can recognize `III` as `3`, but not recognize `IX` as `9`? Is it because some numerals have modern uses, like `IV` now could be short for "intravenous", or that `XI` is Chinese `she`?

How do I correct this?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. What exactly is Siri reading which cause it to 'misspeak'? Is it reading a list of roman numerals? Is it reading a list of Hindu-Arabic numerals?

Comment: It reads some roman numerals as numbers, others as characters. For instance, in Accessibility Inspector, it reads `II, III, VII, VIII, IX, and XII` as `2, 3, 7, 8, 9, and 12`. However, it reads `1, 4, 5, 6, and 10` as the characters `I, I-V, V, V-I, and X`.  Even odder, it reads `11`(XI) as the Latinized Chinese form "she".

Comment: Siri VoiceOver on an iPhone 13 (ios 15.5) is where the displayed behavior for my original post occurred.

Comment: So it reads the text containg 6 as VI? That is what you have written. If you mean it does not read VI as 6 then you need to rewrite your question.

Comment: No. It reads VI as `V I`, not `6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can’t do anything about it.

Long answer, all of this depends on the speech synthesizer being used. Four people that use screen readers like Apple‘s voiceover, or any Windows based screen readers, there are a host of different voices available to suit a persons liking. Each one of those voices has different pronunciation styles, idiosyncrasies, and quirks. All of this depends on the internal rules of the synthesizer. For screen readers, there are internal dictionary‘s to adjust the pronunciation of words to better fit language. Obviously, Siri does not have that.